# MongoDB How sort elements by equalization

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection:

```
{
  _id: some object id,
  title: "Example",
  region: "US"
}
```

I want to sort by elements by equalization.

For example, if `region = US`, put all elements with a region "US" at the beginning of the results and after them elements with a different region.

Can I do this in a MongoDB query? If yes, so how?

Comment: Post here what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, by using [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

we need the pipeline stages [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$Sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)

Below query will give the desired output

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
  {
    $project: { _id: 1, title: 1, region: 1,
      isCountryUS: {
        $cond: { if: {
                      $eq: [ "US", "$region" ]
                     },
                 then: 1,
                 else: 0
        }
      }
     }
  },
  {
    $sort: { isCountryUS: -1, region: 1 }
  },
  {   
    $project: { _id: 1, title: 1, region: 1 }
  }
]);
```

Let us have our collection with sample of 20 documents

```
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737312","title":"Example 1","region":"US"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737313","title":"Example 2","region":"US"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737314","title":"Example 3","region":"US"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737315","title":"Example 4","region":"US"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737316","title":"Example 5","region":"IND"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737317","title":"Example 6","region":"IND"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737318","title":"Example 7","region":"CAN"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737319","title":"Example 8","region":"CAN"}
{"_id":"5d19bb67973523001073731a","title":"Example 9","region":"UK"}
{"_id":"5d19bb67973523001073731b","title":"Example 10","region":"UK"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737320","title":"Example 20","region":"US"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737321","title":"Example 12","region":"MEX"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737322","title":"Example 17","region":"MEX"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737323","title":"Example 14","region":"MEX"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737324","title":"Example 15","region":"FRA"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737325","title":"Example 16","region":"FRA"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737326","title":"Example 13","region":"ARG"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737327","title":"Example 18","region":"ARG"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737328","title":"Example 19","region":"GER"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737329","title":"Example 11","region":"GER"}
```

When we execute the first [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) we get the below result
you can see for our convenience to get our desired result we have introduced a new attribute `isCountryUS`

```
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737312","title":"Example 1","region":"US","isCountryUS":1}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737313","title":"Example 2","region":"US","isCountryUS":1}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737314","title":"Example 3","region":"US","isCountryUS":1}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737315","title":"Example 4","region":"US","isCountryUS":1}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737316","title":"Example 5","region":"IND","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737317","title":"Example 6","region":"IND","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737318","title":"Example 7","region":"CAN","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737319","title":"Example 8","region":"CAN","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19bb67973523001073731a","title":"Example 9","region":"UK","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19bb67973523001073731b","title":"Example 10","region":"UK","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737320","title":"Example 20","region":"US","isCountryUS":1}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737321","title":"Example 12","region":"MEX","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737322","title":"Example 17","region":"MEX","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737323","title":"Example 14","region":"MEX","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737324","title":"Example 15","region":"FRA","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737325","title":"Example 16","region":"FRA","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737326","title":"Example 13","region":"ARG","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737327","title":"Example 18","region":"ARG","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737328","title":"Example 19","region":"GER","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737329","title":"Example 11","region":"GER","isCountryUS":0}
```

then after executing the [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) the result will be modified as

```
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737312","title":"Example 1","region":"US","isCountryUS":1}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737313","title":"Example 2","region":"US","isCountryUS":1}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737314","title":"Example 3","region":"US","isCountryUS":1}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737315","title":"Example 4","region":"US","isCountryUS":1}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737320","title":"Example 20","region":"US","isCountryUS":1}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737326","title":"Example 13","region":"ARG","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737327","title":"Example 18","region":"ARG","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737318","title":"Example 7","region":"CAN","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737319","title":"Example 8","region":"CAN","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737324","title":"Example 15","region":"FRA","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737325","title":"Example 16","region":"FRA","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737328","title":"Example 19","region":"GER","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737329","title":"Example 11","region":"GER","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737316","title":"Example 5","region":"IND","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737317","title":"Example 6","region":"IND","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737321","title":"Example 12","region":"MEX","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737322","title":"Example 17","region":"MEX","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737323","title":"Example 14","region":"MEX","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19bb67973523001073731a","title":"Example 9","region":"UK","isCountryUS":0}
{"_id":"5d19bb67973523001073731b","title":"Example 10","region":"UK","isCountryUS":0}
```

So at this stage of pipeline execution we got our desired result, but with one additional attribute(which we introduced to get this desired result). We can filter it out by projecting only the required attributes in the final [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

so our final result will be

```
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737312","title":"Example 1","region":"US"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737313","title":"Example 2","region":"US"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737314","title":"Example 3","region":"US"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737315","title":"Example 4","region":"US"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737320","title":"Example 20","region":"US"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737326","title":"Example 13","region":"ARG"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737327","title":"Example 18","region":"ARG"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737318","title":"Example 7","region":"CAN"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737319","title":"Example 8","region":"CAN"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737324","title":"Example 15","region":"FRA"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737325","title":"Example 16","region":"FRA"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737328","title":"Example 19","region":"GER"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737329","title":"Example 11","region":"GER"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737316","title":"Example 5","region":"IND"}
{"_id":"5d19bb679735230010737317","title":"Example 6","region":"IND"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737321","title":"Example 12","region":"MEX"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737322","title":"Example 17","region":"MEX"}
{"_id":"5d19c0e09735230010737323","title":"Example 14","region":"MEX"}
{"_id":"5d19bb67973523001073731a","title":"Example 9","region":"UK"}
{"_id":"5d19bb67973523001073731b","title":"Example 10","region":"UK"}
```